# When to use intersection and union?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, problem-solving

In a probablity problem how do one come to know that one have to use intersection between two events or union between two events to arrive at the solution?

Comment: A Venn diagram may be helpful, as you can shade the parts corresponding to given data. The use the graphical interpretation of intersection and union.

Comment: Without the context of a problem you want to solve, how can Readers advise you whether intersection or union is appropriate?

Answer (score 2):

If you have n number of events and you are asked to find when at least one of them occurs you have to use union. The keyword is "or".

If you are asked to find probability of all of them occurring together then you have to use intersection. The keyword will be "and".

Venn diagrams will help you understand this better.

Answer (score 0):

$P(A \cap B)$ means the probability that both $A$ and $B$ happen.

$P( A \cup B)$ means the probability that $A$ or $B$ happens. It is ok to have both happening at the same time, and it include the case where exactly one happens.